# Create a MYSQL function in Azure for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, azure

I am unable to create a MYSQL function in **Azure Database for MySQL server** and getting this error

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for
>   this operation    0.047 sec

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Check [GRANT SUPER privilege on Azure Database for MySQL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/06/26/grant-super-privilege-on-azure-database-for-mysql/).

Comment: Could you please post the statement? Do you have DEFINER in the statement? If it does, remove DEFINER clause from the statement and it should work fine.